# IfError function using vlookup in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a vlookup function to search for a value in multiple worksheets that are in a separate workbook.

I am trying to use the IfError function with the vlookup but I am not formatting it correctly.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim item As String
    item = 8

    Dim brange, rbrange, jrange, cdrange, cprange As range
    Set brange = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx")_
                 .Worksheets("BOOKS").range("A2:H51")
    Set rbrange = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx")_
                  .Worksheets("REFERENCE BOOKS").range("A2:H51")
    Set jrange = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx")_
                 .Worksheets("JOURNALS").range("A2:H51")
    Set cdrange = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx")_
                  .Worksheets("CDS").range("A2:H51")
    Set cprange = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx")_
                  .Worksheets("CONFERENCE PROCEEDINGS").range("A2:H51")

    Dim title As String
    title = IfError(VLookup(item, brange, 2, False), _
            IfError(VLookup(item, rbrange, 2, False), _
            IfError(VLookup(item, jrange, 2, False), _
            IfError(VLookup(item, cdrange, 2, False), _
            IfError(VLookup(item, cprange, 2, False), "")))))

End Sub
```

Comment: you will need to use the `Application.Vlookup()`

Comment: Also you will need to use the Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError()`

Comment: I added both `Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError()` and `Application.Vlookup()` and I got `title=""` instead of the actual value

Comment: Do any of your ranges contain the number 8 in column A?

Comment: Yes it is in the brange

Comment: You might want to take a look at how `VLookup` works (https://exceljet.net/things-you-should-know-about-vlookup). If your data is to the left of the lookup value, then you cannot return it using `Vlookup`. You will have to use something like `Index Match`. Also you are not defining your range, even though you are trying - this has nothing to do with your issue, but just saying that you are actually only declaring cprange as range.

Comment: @Niclas my data is to the left to of my range.  What do you mean I haven't defined my range?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your data/worksheet (just 1 of them, if the rest has the same format). Look at the link I wrote. This example illustrates it: https://exceljet.net/sites/default/files/images/articles/inline/VLOOKUP%20only%20looks%20right.png if your lookup value is in column A it does not matter. But if your lookup value is in Column C, this means that you cannot look up data in columns before this (Column A+B).

Comment: my lookup value is in column A.  I can't paste in a picture but my lookup value is in Column A and I want the information that is in Column B

Comment: So this Excel formula should work, right? Post it in `Column I`. Please confirm, so we can convert it into VBA `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8;BOOKS!A2:H51;2;FALSE);IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8;'REFERENCE BOOKS'!A2:H51;2;FALSE);IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8;JOURNALS!A2:H51;2;FALSE);IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8;CDS!A2:H51;2;FALSE);IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8;'CONFERENCE PROCEEDINGS'!A2:H51;2;FALSE);"")))))` you need to add @niclas to highlight me or others :-)

Comment: @Niclas For some reason when I pasted it in it didn't work.  But I typed it in manually and it did work `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8,BOOKS!A2:H51,2,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8,REFERENCE BOOKS!A2:H51,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8,JOURNALS!A2:H51,2,FALSE), IFERROF(VLOOKUP(8,CDS!A2:H51,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(8, CONFERENCE PROCEEDINGS!A2:H51,2,FALSE),"")))))`

Comment: Se my answer below, it should work. At least it did in my test workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to work with `WorksheetFunction` when using `Iferror` and you need to use `Application.VLookup` (read here: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/).
Also `VBA VLookup` is sensitive to datatypes, so when you define `item as string` it will not work. Instead you should use `Variant` to be covered in.
`Dim item As Variant`

Also you need to define these ranges as `Range`. With your current code, you only define `cprange` as a actual range.
Use this instead:
`Dim brange As Range, rbrange As Range, jrange As Range, cdrange As Range, cprange As Range`

```
title = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(item, brange, 2, False), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(item, rbrange, 2, False), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(item, jrange, 2, False), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(item, cdrange, 2, False), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(item, cprange, 2, False), "")))))
```

In generel, it is good practice to use `Option Explicit`. Put this at the absolute first line in your module (outside your procedure).